# Is it ok to use non printable character as empty char in C

Tags: c, printf

I want to print character or nothing using printf in C.

Let's say I have this struct, where index is either printable character or 6 (which is nonprintable character).

```
struct indexed {
    char name;
    char index;
};

struct indexed item = { 'x', 6 };

printf("Indexed char '%c%c' is worth printing", item.name, item.index);
```

This would result in printing 'x' without any space. But the way seems pretty hacky, so...

**Is it ok to use non printable characters in C like that, if so which one would be the best?**

I don't really want to split the printf with if statement and don't want to have extra space behind first char.

Comment: I would not recommend it. If you don't want to print a char, then don't print it. This looks like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me

Comment: Depending on the OS, this can lead to strange side effects. ;) So, no. I wouldn't recommend it. You could print a string with one character, or empty string, which has the same effect but is reliable.

Comment: The idea was more like: They are not printable characters and some of them are pretty outdated, so why not use them like that. Thank you for comments, I'll just create and accept answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like was said in comments, much more reliable solution if you don't want to use if statement nor space is to use '\0' like this:

```
struct indexed {
    char name;
    char index;
};

struct indexed item = { 'x', '\0' };

char temp[] = { item.name, item.index, '\0' };
printf("Indexed char '%s' is worth printing", temp);
```